# How to convert List<int> to List<Float> with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function that returns List But in my case I want to read and display float values. However, this function is a system function I can't update it.

My question is how to convert List to List?

This is the code:

```
characteristic.value.listen((event) async {
  var bleData = SetupModeResponse(data: event);
});
```

Event is by default a List. When I try to declare data as List; I got List cannot assigned to List.

I would be very thankful if you can help me.

Comment: if 'event' is data, then `event.map((i)=>i.toDouble()).toList()`

Comment: You can convert the List<int> to List<double> in flutter using different ways. var list = list.map((i) => i.toDouble()).toList();

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `map` method on list
like that:

```dart
 List<int> intList = [1, 2, 3];
 List<double> doubleList = intList.map((i) => i.toDouble()).toList();
```

You can learn more about dart list mapping here [map method](https://api.dart.dev/be/180360/dart-core/Iterable/map.html)

Comment: I would say this may look and work like a great solution. But when you try to run the `runtimeType` of each value in `doubleList ` it will be `int`. I also tried others workaround. Guess we sticking with this.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
List<int> ints = [1,2,3];
List<double> doubles = List.from(ints);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try this method and see if it works

```
List<int> num = [1,2,3];
List<double> doubles = List.from(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
List<double> doubleList = event.map((i) => i.toDouble()).toList()
```